# C++ Conway's Game of Life - Cygwin Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, cygwin, conways-game-of-life

I'm new to this forum but I could really use some help.
I've been tasked with programming Conway's Game of Life in C++ and compiling in Cygwin (with a makefile). I'm not asking anybody to complete the program for me or anything like that, but I am totally stuck on this one part...
One of the facets of the program is to allow a user to input a text file as a map for the initial grid, rather than using a randomly generated grid.
Here is an example of the format of the .txt file (the numbers and 'X' are purely for example, a file can be any variation of this format):

```
5 (rows)
6 (columns)
-----X
X--X--
------
-XX---
------
```

The 'X' represent spaces with live bacteria, and the '-' represent dead spaces.
Although my program compiles just fine through cygwin, when I run the .exe I get a "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)" error. I've done extensive google searching to this point, but I've found that this error is generally very specific to the program which it concerns, so other solutions aren't of much help to me.
I don't want to spam you guys with a ton of code, so I'm only including my loadFile function for now. If you need more of the code to help, let me know and I'll post it immediately.
Here's what I have so far in my loadFile function:

```
void GamePlay::loadFile(int r, int c, char** newBoard){
  int i;
  //int r;
  //int c;
  //char** newBoard;


  int len;
  int k;

  do{
    r = 0;
    c = 0;
    string filePath;
    cout << "Please enter a file path" << endl;
    cin >> filePath;
    DIR* path = opendir(filePath.c_str());
    string fpath = filePath.c_str();
    dirent* openIn = readdir(path);
    string line;
    string ext = ".txt";
    i = 0;

    while(openIn && i != -1){
        if(openIn->d_type == DT_REG){
            string fileName = openIn->d_name;
            string filePath = fpath + fileName;
            int begExt = fileName.find_last_of(".");
            int endExt = fileName.find_last_of("t");
            string extension = fileName.substr(begExt, endExt);

            ifstream in(filePath.c_str());
            k = 0;

            if(in && ext == extension){
                getline(in,line);
                istringstream(line) >> r;
                getline(in,line);
                istringstream(line) >> c;
                newBoard = new char*[r]; //create multi-d array
                for(int a = 0; a < r; ++a){
                    newBoard[a] = new char[c];
                }

                while(in.good() && i != -1){
                    if(k <= r){
                        if(len == c){
                            for(int g = 0; g < r; ++g){
                                getline(in,line);
                                len = line.size();
                                char* arr = new char[len];
                                memcpy(arr,line.c_str(),len);
                                for(int h = 0; h < c; ++h){
                                    newBoard[g][h] = arr[h];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        /*if(len == c){
                        //newBoard = len*sizeof(char*);
                        for(int a = 0; a < len; ++a){
                        newBoard[a] = r;
                        memcpy(newBoard[a], line, r);
                        }
                        }*/
                        else{
                            cout << "Your column number does not match your grid." << endl;
                            cout << "Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                            i = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        cout << "Your row number does not match your grid." << endl;
                        cout << "Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                        i = -1;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            }
            else{
                cout << "File invalid. Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                i = -1;
            }
            return;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid file path. Please try again with a new file." << endl;
            i = -1;
        }
    }
  }while(i = -1);
}
```

I've also tried using GDB to debug and find where the issue is, but it's way over my head. Sadly all I'm used to using are GUI's such as visual studio and eclipse.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Google 'GDB Tutorial'.  The first link is pretty useful.

Comment: From what I can see, you're trying to open every ".txt" file in a directory, read all of them, and throw away the results (including memory leaks) from all except the last. I'm not entirely convinced that it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using GDB is pretty easy, just

```
gdb [path-to-your-executable]
run
[wait for it to crash]
backtrace
```

And that will tell you where the crash happened. You can also insert breakpoints with

```
break file:line
```

When it stops, use

```
print [some expression]
```

To find information about the current stack frame (variables and all that), then "continue" to move on to the next breakpoint. If necessary, you can also debug remotely using

```
gdb [path-to-your-executable] [process ID]
```

Which is good if your program outputs a lot of information to the terminal screen (because otherwise it will mess with GDB's output).

Comment: Thank you for that. When I used your advice, I was able to get "invalid decimal '0x22DBF0'" right after being prompted to and entering a file path. I'm still not sure what to do with this... Any thoughts?

Comment: @homeofmatt - Seems to be a Cygwin thing, see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/141146

Answer (score 0):

If your initial interest is just in finding where the issue is in your code, you don't necessarily need a debugger; I have never used one and usually manage to get the bugs out of my programs.  You can set up flags and use cout statements to identify where the program is having a problem.  I did this extensively when I used C++ in high school and college.

I entered some cout statements in your code below just so you'd know what I'm talking about.  You haven't already tried this, have you?  Obviously, you run the program and see which flag outputs get generated.  If one comes up and a later one doesn't, you have narrowed down which line of code is messing up your program.

```
    void GamePlay::loadFile(int r, int c, char** newBoard){
      int i;
      //int r;
      //int c;
      //char** newBoard;


      int len;
      int k;

      cout << "flag1";

      do{
        r = 0;
        c = 0;
        string filePath;
        cout << "Please enter a file path" << endl;
        cin >> filePath;

        cout << "flag2";

        DIR* path = opendir(filePath.c_str());
        string fpath = filePath.c_str();
        dirent* openIn = readdir(path);
        string line;
        string ext = ".txt";
        i = 0;

        cout << "flag3";

        while(openIn && i != -1){
            if(openIn->d_type == DT_REG){
                string fileName = openIn->d_name;
                string filePath = fpath + fileName;
                int begExt = fileName.find_last_of(".");
                int endExt = fileName.find_last_of("t");
                string extension = fileName.substr(begExt, endExt);

                cout << "flag4";

                ifstream in(filePath.c_str());
                k = 0;

                if(in && ext == extension){
                    getline(in,line);
                    istringstream(line) >> r;
                    getline(in,line);
                    istringstream(line) >> c;
                    newBoard = new char*[r]; //create multi-d array
                    for(int a = 0; a < r; ++a){
                        newBoard[a] = new char[c];
                    }

                    cout << "flag5";

                    while(in.good() && i != -1){
                        if(k <= r){
                            if(len == c){
                                for(int g = 0; g < r; ++g){
                                    getline(in,line);
                                    len = line.size();
                                    char* arr = new char[len];
                                    memcpy(arr,line.c_str(),len);
                                    for(int h = 0; h < c; ++h){
                                        newBoard[g][h] = arr[h];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            /*if(len == c){
                            //newBoard = len*sizeof(char*);
                            for(int a = 0; a < len; ++a){
                            newBoard[a] = r;
                            memcpy(newBoard[a], line, r);
                            }
                            }*/
                            else{
                                cout << "Your column number does not match your grid." << endl;
                                cout << "Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                                i = -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            cout << "Your row number does not match your grid." << endl;
                            cout << "Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                            i = -1;
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    cout << "File invalid. Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                    i = -1;
                }
                return;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Invalid file path. Please try again with a new file." << endl;
                i = -1;
            }
        }
        cout << "flag6";
      }while(i = -1);
    }
```

Comment: Yea I know what you mean, I've been abusing print statements instead of debugging for the past couple years that I've been programming. I haven't tried it on here yet though, because I have absolutely no idea what my error is really saying.
I'll post back after I try this.

Comment: Alright so I found that the error occurs at:

dirent* openIn = readdir(path);

Comment: On comment, based on this:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v610.edclv/rtoped.htm ...the whole opendir function is for opening directories, not single files.  Why do you need to open a whole directory just to read from one file?

Comment: Yeah, I think path is not a directory.

Comment: Okay yea, but I'm trying to grab the file name. When I input a directory, it works but gives me an error because of the "if(openIn->d_type == DT_REG)" check.
I don't know how to get the file name so that I pass the if statement without getting a segmentation fault

Comment: I think you are beyond my knowledge of that part of C++.  I only ever used fstream.  Sorry.